# create Grafana dashboard dynamically from influxdb-measurements

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have measurements like these in influx

```
weather_sensor,crop=blueberries,plot=1,temp=13.6 1472515200000000000
weather_sensor,crop=blueberries,plot=2,temp=14.0 1472515200000000000
weather_sensor,crop=blueberries,plot=1,rain=0 1472515200000000000
weather_sensor,crop=blueberries,plot=2,rain=37 1472515200000000000
weather_sensor,crop=apples,plot=3,temp=15.4 1472515200000000000
weather_sensor,crop=apples,plot=4,temp=15.8 1472515200000000000
weather_sensor,crop=apples,plot=3,rain=102 1472515200000000000
weather_sensor,crop=apples,plot=4,rain=44 1472515200000000000
```

Is it possible to dynamically create the following dashboard from this data alone:

- dropdown to select the crop
- when crop "blueberries" is selected: charts for all blueberry plots are displayed
- the charts show temperature and rainfall for each plot

When a new measurement arrives like

```
weather_sensor,crop=strawberries,plot=9,temp=12.2 1572515200000000000
```

There is a new element "strawberries" in the dropdown, leading to a dashboard with one chart ("strawberries plot 9")

All this without knowing beforehand which crops and plots there are (like reading from a DB the structure of the farming operation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `crop` must be Influxdb tag. Create Grafana dashboard variable, e.g. `crop` from the query, e.g. `SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "crop"`. Then use this variable in the graph panel query, e.g.

```
SELECT mean("temp"), mean("rain") 
FROM "metrics" 
WHERE "crop" =~ /^$crop$/ AND $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($__interval), "plot" fill(null)
```

I don't have your data, so this query may still need some minor tweaks. It is to give you and idea.

If you need dedicated panels per plot, then define also `plot` variable, with crop filter condition, e.g. `SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "plot" WHERE "crop" =~ /^$crop$/` and use panel repeating feature for this `plot` variable + use also filtering with `$plot` in the panel query.